# PHP Ajax file upload not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Please help me find the problem here. I am trying to upload a file via AJAX but For some reason which I am unaware of this code has refused to work i.e uploaded file is not copied to the location.

```
function save()
{
    var fileUpload = $("#files").get(0);
    var files = fileUpload.files;
    var data = new FormData();
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length ; i++) {
       data.append('files',files[i],files[i].name);
    }

    var datastring = $("#businessform").serializeArray();
    $.each(datastring,function(key,input){
        data.append(input.name,input.value);
    });

    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../include/update_ajax.php",
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: data,
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                //do something
            },
            error: function(){
                  alert('error handling here');
            }
        });
 }
```

Here's the PHP

```
        $success = 0;
        $logo = "";
        $logo_error = 0;
        $sql = "update business set businessname=:bname, phone=:phone, email=:email where vendorid = :id";
        $fields = array(
            ':bname'=>$_POST['businessname'],
            ':phone'=>$_POST['businessphone'],
            ':email'=>$_POST['businessemail'],               
            ':id'=>$_POST['vendorid']
        );
        $q=$con->update_query($sql,$fields);
        if($q)
        {
            //save logo
            $businessid = $con->lastID;
            if(!empty($_FILES['files']['tmp_name']))
            {
                $ext=pathinfo($_FILES['files']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                if(strcasecmp($ext, "jpeg") == 0 || strcasecmp($ext, "jpg") == 0 || strcasecmp($ext, "png") == 0)
                {
                    $logo = "logo".$businessid;
                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'], UPLOADS_FOLDER.$logo);
                }
                else
                {
                    $logo_error = 1;
                }

            }
            $success = 1;
        }
        echo json_encode(array('success'=>$success, 'logo_error'=>$logo_error));
```

The serialized form appended is sent and inserted without issues but the uploaded file is not sent this way. Please what are my doing wrong and what's the better way.

Thank you so much.

Comment: have you done any debugging?

Comment: use `var datastring = FormData($("#businessform")[0]);` instead of `var datastring = $("#businessform").serializeArray();`

Comment: var datastring = FormData($("#businessform")[0]); did not work.

Comment: Check out this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44536433/unable-to-send-the-multipart-file-from-jquery-to-spring-controller-using-ajax/44544831#44544831

Comment: try `print_r($_FILES)` in your php file

Comment: Ok, so i did the print_r($_FILES) and saw that my files were actually posted. Thanks a lot it saves now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to append files in `FormData()` just put Form tag selector in side `FormData($("#businessform")[0])`;

```
function save()
{
    var datastring = FormData($("#businessform")[0]);

    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../include/update_ajax.php",
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: data,
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                //do something
            },
            error: function(){
                  alert('error handling here');
            }
        });
 }
```

Comment: Please will the file upload be posted as well?